# Converting a particular line from Postgresql to mysql

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I run a couple of queries on my postgres database daily and now I've decided to learn MySQL and decided to migrate my database and queries to the MySQL server.

Unfortunately, I have trouble converting certain parts of my queries especially the one below:

```
DATE_PART('day', DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE) +  
        '1 MONTH - 1 DAY'::INTERVAL)::INTEGER
```

Any idea how I can convert this to work on MySql?

Comment: explain, what are you trying to get from that code?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DAY(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE)) Day
```

Output:

```
| DAY |
-------
|  28 |
```

or artificially applying the same logic

```
SELECT DAY(DATE_SUB(DATE_ADD(DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_DATE ,'%Y-%m-01'), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) Day
```

Here is working example **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/8157)**

Comment: @user2118727 Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the last day of the current month

> DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE) --> reduce the date to (first day)
>   the current month '1 MONTH - 1 DAY'::INTERVAL --> add another month
>   and get one day back

MySQL has [`LASTDAY(date)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_last-day), so the query would translate to `LASTDAY(now())` then you can extract the day with [`DAY(date)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofmonth).